# Докладный митап в Санкт-Петербурге: сбор мнений

Tags: обсуждение

Пару дней назад у меня появилась идея организовать небольшой митап в Санкт-Петербурге, на который могли бы прийти участники сообщества и представить доклад на интересующую тему, а желающие - послушать выступающих по какой-то теме, в которой они хотели бы разобраться. Каких-то рамок у тем докладов нет, кроме пожелания, чтобы это были не слишком узкоспециализированные доклады - можно прийти с рассказом "Моя битва за тайм-менеджмент", который будет интересен многим, но "Концепция сборщика мусора Shenandoah в JVM" будет неактуальной для большинства пришедших (если только вдруг на митап не решат прийти одни джависты). Например, я был бы готов выступить со следующими темами:

- Распределенные системы: проблемы, их решения и почему решения не работают
- Принципы работы хранилища данных Cassandra
- Принципы работы поискового движка ElasticSearch
- Принципы работы системы оркестрации Kubernetes
- Kubernetes, Aurora, Marathon, Rancher, Nomad: сравнение существующих систем оркестрации
- Как протестировать автоматизацию инфраструктуры?
- Chef, Ansible, Puppet, SaltStack: сравнение существующих систем менеджмента конфигурации
- Event Sourcing и CQRS: что это такое, с чем я столкнулся, когда решил написать приложение на этих концепциях, и в чем я не согласен с Мартином Фаулером
- Документирование API веб-приложения: существующие инструменты

Сейчас это все существует только в виде идеи, и я хочу понять, насколько это вообще актуально и хватит ли для реализации спикеров. Ниже есть несколько ответов-голосований - оставьте, пожалуйста, свое мнение плюсиками и/или комментариями.

Comment: Кто минусует и зачем, выйдите из сумрака! )

Comment: @Kromster нужно запретить минусы!

Comment: Так, а почему не поехать просто на [remoteCamp](http://remotecamp.ru/) о котором писал [@NicolasChabanovsky](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38368352#38368352) ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский думаю, что там будет немного другая направленность докладов, и не готов выезжать с палаткой :)

Comment: Могу по видеосвязи рассказать что-нибудь про документацию.

Comment: С первой и предпоследней темой вполне можете податься на dotNext, они как раз хотят на следующей конференции больше архитектурных докладов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin было бы очень клево

Comment: мб трансляцию с хорошим качеством запилить, или видео с хорошим качеством с вставкой картинок из презентаций(уже после)?

Comment: По моему прекрасная идея. Лучше про JVM. С удовольствием помогу-поучаствую в процессе организации, удовольствие помочь в такой замечательной идее. ВК в профиле если вдруг понадоблюсь если даже нет, то приду с удовольствием просто послушать.

Comment: Тема заглохла или идёт какая-то невидимая работа под капотом?

Comment: @AK боюсь, я пока в небольшом аду.

Answer (score 21):

Я живу **не в Санкт-Петербурге**, и мне было бы интересно поучаствовать в событии в таком формате в качестве докладчика/слушателя, если бы оно проходило **в моем городе**

Comment: Я бы поучаствовал в качестве слушателя, а не докладчика. (Если вы тоже как и я хотите послушать выступления но без доклада -- плюсуйте и ответ etki и мой комментарий)

Comment: @AK т. е. вы предлагаете трансляцию?

Comment: @D-side Однозначно. Сейчас перечитал формулировку и понял, что это не очевидно. Надо либо разделить ответ на тех, кто "в другом городе и готов приехать" или "в другом городе, не приеду, но хочу посмотреть трансляцию", либо определиться, что конкретно понимается.

Comment: @AK подозреваю, что просто не идёт расчёт на то, что кто-либо поедет в Петербург только на этот митап.

Comment: @AK переформатировал для однозначности

Comment: в сторону: опросники лучше как "Общие сообщения" публиковать

Answer (score 18):

Я живу **в Петербурге** и хотел бы принять участие в подобном событии в качестве **слушателя**

Comment: Живу в спб пришел бы в качестве слушателя

Answer (score 5):

Я живу **в Петербурге** и хотел бы принять участие в подобном событии в качестве **докладчика**

Comment: А зачем минус сюда ставить? Не хочешь доклад готовить -- пропусти эту версию. Не понимаю логики. Кто минусовал -- поясните.

Comment: @AK по-моему, просто кто-то метаненавистник и прошелся тут по всему минусом.

Comment: @AK не хотят докладчиков из Петербурга.

Comment: Если кому-то интересна тема про `Apache Flink` - готов что-нибудь рассказать :)

Comment: .NET готовлю... впрочем, у нас уже крайне активная юзер-группа http://spbdotnet.org